# Using LambdaMetaFactory to expose getters causes class cast exception

Tags: java, lambda-metafactory

I'm using LambdaMetaFactory to expose getters. I have a POJO with many fields and I don't know which fields are going to be populated. I'm trying to avoid both an extended if statement and also reflection.

So here's a snippet from my POJO:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyPojo {

private String email;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String zipCode;

private String city;

private String street;

private String country;

...

    }
```

and here's my method which get's my values from all of the getters:

```
    public static String getValueFromGetterMethodName(String fieldName, MyPojo myPojo) {

    String methodName = constructGetterMethodName(fieldName);
    final MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType getChangeDataMethodType = methodType(String.class, MyPojo.class);

    try {
        final CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "apply", methodType(Function.class),
                methodType(Object.class, Object.class),
                lookup.findVirtual(MyPojo.class, methodName, methodType(String.class)),
                getChangeDataMethodType);

        Function<MyPojo, String> getterFunction = (Function<MyPojo, String>) site.getTarget()
                .invokeExact();
        return getterFunction.apply(myPojo);
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("Error getting getter method ref: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The problem is that this line here:

```
 Function<MyPojo, String> getterFunction = (Function<MyPojo, String>) site.getTarget()
                .invokeExact();
```

produces an Unchecked Class Cast warning. I know we're supposed to avoid those. This code works quite well. I'm not sure how to change it to avoid the class cast exception. CallSite doesn't accept parameters.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea unless you really know what you're doing. You're not supposed to use LambdaMetafactory in "normal" production code, unless you're building a util tool or a code manipulation tool

Comment: i appreciate your input. if it's ill-advised though it should be always ill-advised whether you know what you are doing or not. i haven't anywhere on the net where they say it's ill-advised though. this code is working beautifully and makes me happy. b/c as me expose more user data for update all i have to do is add a field to my request POJO and it's done & dusted

Comment: What's the CCE you're seeing? Can you include the error message?

Comment: I miscommunicated. It produces an unchecked class cast warning. So it does work quite well. I can give it a list of field names and it constructs the getters and retrieves the values for me

Comment: The warning means that there will be no runtime check about the correctness of the cast to a generic type. Since this can’t be checked, there is no way around `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in this specific case. Just make sure to limit its scope as much as possible, e.g. it should work when the annotation is applied to the `getterFunction` variable only. Though `javac` doesn’t generate a warning here.

Comment: I never had any question what this warning means. As my post said we are supposed to avoid these. Suppress warnings is not acceptable for this use case. I was hoping someone had a change that would make it go away. As it is, I did it in a less complex way l which was said because this code is pretty cool in what it does.

Comment: Since the meaning implies that there is no “change that would make it go away”, the meaning is relevant. It also implies that even if you find a way (other than suppressing the warning) to make it disappear, it’s just a flaw of the compiler that may get fixed the next version.